# Previous screen time is not updating in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, time, date-format

I'm using stateless Widget in my application.
By using this single line I can get the output.

```
  DateFormat('HH:mma').format(now).
```

1.problem is when screen is moving to another screen and back to previous screen at that time time which I have implemented is not updating.
2. time is not updating when I do not touch the screen. and its updating once I touched the screen.

Is there any possibilities to overcome this behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: from flutter docs: *A widget is either stateful or stateless. If a widget can change—when a user interacts with it, for example—it’s stateful* ... your widget can change then why it stateless ?

Comment: I have created a stateless widget for header section. I want to display the current time into header section.:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a widget that for example refreshes every second, you could use  a `StreamBuilder`. For example

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream:
        Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1)),
    builder: (context, snapshot) =>
        Text(DateFormat('HH:mm:ssa').format(DateTime.now())),
  );
}
```